# Region(-32000,-32000,160,27) outside any screen - subsequent actions might not work as expected

Tags: sikuli

I am new to the sikuli , while running my script i found an error "[error] Region(-32000,-32000,160,27) outside any screen - subsequent actions might not work as expected" .

Please someone help me out how to over come from this issue.

My script as follows : Open an Window App  if the App is not opened and if is already opened then focus on App

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from sikuli.Sikuli import *

class LaunchClient(object):

    def __init__(self):
           self.appCoordinates = (0, 0, 1024, 768)

    def startApp(self):
           clientApp = App("XYZ")
               if not clientApp.window():
                    App.open(r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ABC \\XYZ.exe"); wait(2)
              clientApp.focus(); wait(1)

    def runTest(self):
        self.startApp()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
         client = LaunchClient()
         client.runTest()
```

The Error message "[error] Region(-32000,-32000,160,27) outside any screen - subsequent actions might not work as expected" display when the window app is already opened . Error not observed while opening the App .

Answer (score 0):

It means your app is reacing the borders of your screen. For example, you can open "Notepad" and drag it off the screen so you can only see half of it. Then there is a part outside the screen.

That is what this error means.

It will also give this message when a few pixels (for the app) are outside the screen.

It is just a way from Sikuli telling you it can only click on the things that are on the screen not outside it. If you make the app full screen it mostly disapears. (Or you app is opening while touching an edge of the screen.)